# Row created in mysql with no error, but no data inserted

Tags: php, mysql

Very new at this. I submit my input form, no errors come up. When I go to check the entry into myphpadmin, a row was created, but all the fields are blank.

Not sure what is going on as my text code with only 4 entries works.

```
<?php

$subscribingcompany= $_POST["subscribingcompany"];
$biztype= $_POST["biztype"];
$sitename= $_POST["sitename"];
$siteadd1= $_POST["siteadd1"];
$city1= $_POST["city1"];
$zip1= $_POST["zip1"];
$state1= $_POST["state1"];
$country1= $_POST["country1"];
$biladd1= $_POST["biladd1"];
$city2= $_POST["city2"];
$zip2= $_POST["zip2"];
$state2= $_POST["state2"];
$country2= $_POST["country2"];
$fename= $_POST["fename"];
$lename= $_POST["lename"];
$email1= $_POST["email1"];
$phone1= $_POST["phone1"];
$foname= $_POST["foname"];
$loname= $_POST["loname"];
$email2= $_POST["email2"];
$phone2= $_POST["phone2"];
$effdate= $_POST["effdate"];
$camquantity= $_POST["camquantity"];
$currency= $_POST["currency"];
$quantity= $_POST["quantity"];

$database="greenguy_cbrsandbox";
$table="DesignPartner"; 

//Create connection and select database 
$con= mysql_connect("example.com", "greenguy_ccb", "password88") or         die(mysql_error());
echo "connected";  
mysql_select_db("$database", $con) or die(mysql_error());
echo"database found";

 //Insert into Table
 $insert =  "INSERT INTO $table 
            (id, subscribingcompany, biztype, sitename, siteadd1,   city1, zip1, state1, country1, biladd1, city2, zip2, state2, country2, fename, lename, email1, phone1, foname, loname, email2, phone2, effdate, camquantity, currency, quantity) 
        VALUES  
            (DEFAULT,'$subscribingcompany','$biztype','$sitename','$siteadd1','$city1','$zip1','$state1','$country1','$biladd1','$city2','$zip2','$state2','$country2','$fename','$lename','$email1','$phone1','$foname','$loname','$email2','$phone2','$effdate','$camquantity','$currency','$quantity')";

$results =mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());

echo"data inserted succesfully";    

mysql_close($con); 
  ?>
```

Comment: FYI inserting data into the database without escaping it is just asking for trouble. Look into mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: first check all the data you are passing from form is coming to your php file..

Answer (score 0):

You Insert query is working properly as you have provided the auto increment functionality
  row is getting created but rest of the values are not getting inserted please echo your query during execution .

use **echo $insert** to know what is getting inserted when query is executing.

Comment: Aha, it looks like it's just inserting the table column names and the values. Somehow it's not retrieving the values from the form. So would the error be in the html input form or in the php insert code?

Comment: just echo the form values you are posting so that you will come to know whether values getting posted in to your php  page then insert them into insert query.